# Looking for specific CRM or Membercare software to handle multi-relationship

Tags: crm, saas

I'm looking for a specific form of software for a client of mine. This fell into a realm I'm not too familiar with. My initial thought has been a CRM (or a membercare system of some sort) but I'm not sure if this is *actually* what they want/need.

**The case is**:

In order to respect their wish of privacy the case is fabricated but is similar:

The Company, "Dentist Hub" is a service/management tool which sign up dentists (these are the **clients**).

the Dentist Hub is contacted by e.g. insurance companies or government institutions about setting up a person (we call those the **customer**) with a dentist (the client).

So the "Dentist Hub" is functioning as a, well, "hub" (or management) between dentists and assigning clients to them.

A dentist can log in and see all customers assign to him/her.
The dentist cannot see other customers than those assigned.
The dentist can communicate via messaging system within this solution to the company "Dentist Hub"

So, it's kind of a middle management software, where there are Clients (dentists) and there are Customers. Each customer is assigned to a Client (dentist) and the dentist can log into this system and see information about the Customer they have received.

I hope I explained what I'm looking well otherwise let me know and I can elaborate.

Best

Answer (score 1):

I believe a CRM can work for this. I recommend looking at:

[SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) - a fork/successor/improvement on the old community version of SugarCRM.

- Can be self-hosted since opensource, and is PHP/MySql based.
- Dentist organisation can be setup as "Account".
- Customers can be set up as "Contacts" and then assigned to a Dentist Account.
- You can setup logins for Dentists and restrict access to their Dentist Account.
- Emails can be sent between Dentist and Customer, provided you set up the email server and other associated details etc.
- You can record notes/calls etc, against each Customer if necessary.
- You can add any additional fields required via its "Studio".
- Since it evolved from SugarCRM, it has it's own community, user/developer documentation, etc.
- It probably has much more than you need. So you may have to hide or disable some of the modules.

I recommend installing it, and play around with its functionality, so that you get a better idea on how to proceed.